# Log4Net FixFlags enum empty?

Tags: log4net

Implementing a BufferingAppenderSkeleton in log4net and want to optimize the volatile default data. However the FixFlags enum seems to be empty. I've decompiled it and this is what I get:
[image]

Anyone know how we control the fix flags, since they refactored? (log4net 1.2.11)

Comment: log4net 2.0 ? I thought 1.2.11 was the latest version.

Comment: Please don't use the "fix" tag unless your question is about the Financial Information eXchange protocol.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see is FixFlags still part of the current source base (you can download the source, no need for decompiling):

[source log4net -> FixFlags](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Core/LoggingEvent.cs?view=markup)

And in the unittest it is still tested, nothing changed there.

Comment: You are right. I decompiled my assembly with dotpeek and the enum is actually populated. For some reason, intellisense finds the above and gives me a compile error.